# How to change RecyclerView Card's color dynamically

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that displays cards of same size and similar content. Does anyone knows how I would go about changing the cards color depending on the object it holds? So object "A" would have a blue card and object "B" would have a red card. I've seen visual design in the web accomplishing this but I was wondering if anyone would have sample code or suggestion on how to accomplish this.

Below is the "material design" cards I have on my development app:

[image: material design cards]

Comment: Post some code. What does your cardView layout look like? What are the conditions that determine the color of the cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I found a great way to change the color dynamically for things like the new cards feature on Material Design. A how-to can be found [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Dynamic-Color-using-Palettes). This code allows you to generate the palette synchronously when you have access to the underlying image loading thread. To have access to these nifty new features, make sure to compile the library on your grade.build file like so:

```
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this (if you know before hand what color a card should have) is to save the background color in the data object for the card.

If it's position based you could override [RecyclerView.Adapter.getItemViewType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) to distinguish what color you want for a position. 
This way can also be used if you want to use random colors for cards.